# creating 2 columns from 1 main column in the same table

Tags: sql

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [Value]                       
FROM [OnlineQnres].[dbo].[tmp_DataSets]
WHERE [VariableID] in ('1')
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1000 [Value]
FROM [OnlineQnres].[dbo].[tmp_oDataSets]
WHERE [VariableID] in ('4')
```

Providing a more updated Detail

Hi All, I have this select query above using UNION ALL. There is a column called Value and VariableID in tmp_datasets table. I need to create 2 separate columns and name them val1 for variableID is 1 and val2 if variableID is 4. If i use UNION ALL it works it creates 2000 records with the first 1000 as val1 records and next 1000 as val2 records but does not separate out into 2 sep columns. How do i separate this value column in 2 separate columns as stated above.

I have 2 columns

- `VALUE` which has values `TEST56,TEST57,230,245`
- VARIABLEID = 1 and 4
- TEST56 AND TEST57 comes under variableid == 1
- 230 and 245 comes under variableid == 4

So based on this above example, I want to create a view where I have 2 columns called val1 if variableid == 1 and val2 if variable id == 4.

So it should look something like this

- val1 = should show test56 and test57
- val2 = should show 230 and 245

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you include data from `tmp_DataSets` table ?

Comment: I have a 2 sep columns in this table called tmp_DataSets - They are "Value" and "VarID". I am creating 2 aliases - value as GUID and value as siteID. This value alias is differentiated by VarID. SO value as GUID and VarID = 1 should have all records under alias GUID and value as siteID and VarID = 4 should have all records under alias siteID. So TEST1 and TEST2 are records that should come under GUID alias column and 20 and 40 should come under siteID alias column. The main Value column in the tmp_DataSets table has all these values combined together.

Comment: So to make things easier here is my code. Basically i need to combine these 2 sep select statements together and show them as 1 view with GUID and siteID side by side - 2 sep columns in the view SELECT TOP 1000 [Value] as [GUID]
  FROM [OnlineQnres].[dbo].[tmp_DataSets]
  WHERE [VariableID] in ('1')
SELECT TOP 1000 [Value] as [siteID]
  FROM [OnlineQnres].[dbo].[LuminosoDataSets]
  WHERE [VariableID] in ('4')

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide additional details there instead of in comments. Editing the question allows people to see the information when reading your question, and it allows you to properly format code and SQL so that it's readable. Thanks.

Comment: I apologize, I updated my query in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple case statements should do what I think you want:

```
SELECT TOP 1000
[Variable] 
CASE [VariableID]
  WHEN 1 THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END AS Val1,     
CASE [VariableID]
  WHEN 4 THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END AS Val2                       
FROM [OnlineQnres].[dbo].[tmp_DataSets]
WHERE [VariableID] = 1 or [VariableID] = 4
```

SQLFiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/825f2/8/0

Comment: llion thats exactly what I needed. Unfortunately I cant give you the answer is useful as its not allowing me. but its the best answer i have got so far. thanks again mate

Comment: i need 15 reputation, i only have 8. Thats why cant give it useful.